# How to have conditional design attributes in aura components?

Tags: lightning, aura, screen-flow, lightning-record-page, design-attributes

I want my aura to be exposed on both flowscreen and lightning record page. I have implemented the interfaces.

But I want different design attributes to be visible when I configure it for record page vs flows.

In LWC, we can define different properties under respective target. Is there a way to achieve the same behaviour in aura components?

Comment: Why implement in Aura instead of LWC in the first place? Is there a good technical reason?

Comment: answering on behalf of @sakshi, We are exposing a container component that needs to support dynamic rendering of Aura/LWC component depending on configuration, since we cannot embed Aura inside an LWC component, we need to make the container component an Aura component